Laravel Echo with Reverb Not Listening to Events in Real-Time and Showing Pusher Errors
I'm facing an issue with Laravel Echo where I'm using Reverb for broadcasting events instead of Pusher. However, when I try to listen to events in real-time, nothing happens until I reload the page. Additionally, I keep encountering errors related to Pusher even though I'm not using Pusher at all.
Environment:

Laravel 11 Vite

.env :
APP_NAME=PUSAT-OTP
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:6JdemGaC90WRlzdHu67O5Jw6qKaTrW6XuHPF0GX4eQM=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost:18080
APP_PORT=8080

# Database and Redis
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbotp_project
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PORT=6379

# Broadcasting
BROADCAST_DRIVER=reverb
BROADCAST_CONNECTION=reverb

# Reverb Configuration
REVERB_APP_ID=946019
REVERB_APP_KEY=0hi8cdtq5c1fxvx51ggy
REVERB_APP_SECRET=binhrda9ycj51ybemsid
REVERB_HOST=0.0.0.0
REVERB_PORT=8080
REVERB_SCHEME=http
REVERB_SERVER=reverb

VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY="${REVERB_APP_KEY}"
VITE_REVERB_HOST="${REVERB_HOST}"
VITE_REVERB_PORT="${REVERB_PORT}"
VITE_REVERB_SCHEME="${REVERB_SCHEME}"

Here’s a summary of my setup:
Controller:
public function storeSms(Request $request)
{
    // Other code...

    event(new SmsOTPUpdated($smsOtp->orderOtp));

    // Return response...
}

Event
class SmsOTPUpdated implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    public $orderOtp;

    public function __construct(OrderOtp $orderOtp)
    {
        $this->orderOtp = $orderOtp;
    }

    public function broadcastOn(): Channel
    {
        return new Channel('order.' . $this->orderOtp->id);
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['sms' => $this->orderOtp->smsOtp->sms];
    }
}

Frontend (Blade with JavaScript):
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    @foreach ($orders as $order)
        Echo.channel('order.{{ $order->id }}')
            .listen('SmsOTPUpdated', (e) => {
                let smsElement = document.getElementById('sms-{{ $order->id }}');
                if (smsElement) {
                    smsElement.innerHTML = `<pre>${e.sms}</pre>`;
                }
            });
    @endforeach
});

Error :
[2024-08-20 16:19:57] local.ERROR: Pusher error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8080... 
Steps I've Taken:

Ensured that BROADCAST_DRIVER is set to reverb in .env.
Cleared configuration and cache using php artisan config:clear and php artisan cache:clear.
Verified that there are no references to Pusher in my configuration files or event classes.
Tried running php artisan queue:work to see if that resolves the issue.

Problem:

The event doesn’t listen in real-time until I reload the page.
The error message still shows references to Pusher even though I’ve configured Laravel to use Reverb.

My Questions:

Why is Laravel still attempting to use Pusher despite my configuration for Reverb?
How can I ensure that events are listened to in real-time with Reverb, and get rid of these Pusher-related errors?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!


Laravel Reverb uses pusher-php-server, as of this these errors make sense.
Did you run php artisan reverb:start
It looks like your not using ssl, check this part of the reverb doku Reverb SSL
Your error seems like that Laravel itself can't connect to the Laravel Reverb server, I don't think this has to do with Laravel Echo

